# sudo: apt-get: command not found linux server

Tags: linux, sudo, apt-get, apt

I am using a Linux server andtrying to install the jdk package. But when i try sudo apt , I get the following error:

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

The version of Linux is:

```
3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can't figure out whats wrong

Comment: Is this Debian or Ubuntu? Run `lsb_release -a`

Comment: What _flavour_ of Linux is it? `apt-get` is installed mainly on Debian and derivatives.

Comment: @Tim, SiKing, How to check that. Sorry I am completely new to Linux. Tried `cat/proc/version` and `cat/etc/*-release` and bothe returned `No such file or directory`

Comment: @Tim, `-bash: lsb_release: command not found`. This is what I got

Comment: How did you install the Linux?

Comment: @Tim, I did not. Its a server. I just access it to run Python and now I need to set up a database in it

Comment: Can you find the documentation from when you bought it / hired it?

Comment: @Tim, ok I will try fetching that and get back to you

Comment: There is no one definitive way to find out what distro you are on. See this: https://siking.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/getting-linux-distro-name-and-version/ for a start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you have CentOS on your server based on Linux version. You can try Yum instead. For example:

```
sudo yum install ...
```

Comment: Works. How did you figure out the OS. Is there any command for it

Comment: You can use cat /etc/redhat-release. However, if you put the version number in a search engine it will give you the clue.

Comment: @DigantaBharali cat /etc/os-release also works for getting OS. I have checked on ubuntu, SUSE and Centos.